# Can I use this parallel iterator pattern with Cython?

Tags: python, c++11, openmp, cython

With C++11 I have been using the following pattern for implementing a graph data structure with parallel iterators. Nodes are just indices, edges are entries in an adjacency data structure. For iterating over all nodes, a function (lambda, closure...) is passed to a `parallelForNodes` method and called with each node as an argument. Iteration details are nicely encapsulated in the method.

Now I would like to try the same concept with Cython. Cython provides the `cython.parallel.prange` function which uses OpenMP for parallelizing a loop over a range. For parallelism to work, Python's Global Interpreter Lock needs to be deactivated with the `nogil=True` parameter. Without the GIL, using Python objects is not allowed, which makes this tricky.

Is it possible to use this approach with Cython?

```
class Graph:

    def __init__(self, n=0):
        self.n = n
        self.m = 0  
        self.z = n  # max node id
        self.adja = [[] for i in range(self.z)]
        self.deg = [0 for i in range(self.z)]

    def forNodes(self, handle):
        for u in range(self.z):
            handle(u)

    def parallelForNodes(self, handle):
        # first attempt which will fail...
        for u in prange(self.z, nogil=True):
            handle(u)


# usage 

def initialize(u):
    nonlocal ls
    ls[u] = 1

G.parallelForNodes(initialize)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, things cannot be Python objects without the GIL.

```
from cython.parallel import prange

cdef class Graph:
    cdef int n, m, z

    def __cinit__(self, int n=0):
        self.z = n  # max node id

    cdef void parallelForNodes(self, void (*handle)(int) nogil) nogil:
        cdef int u
        for u in prange(self.z, nogil=True):
            handle(u)
```

The biggest catch there is that our function pointer was *also* `nogil`.

`parallelForNodes` does not have to be `nogil` itself, but there's no reason for it not to be.

Then we need a **C** function to call:

```
cdef int[100] ls
cdef void initialize(int u) nogil:
    global ls
    ls[u] = 1
```

and it just works!

```
Graph(100).parallelForNodes(initialize)

# Print it!
cdef int[:] ls_ = ls
print(list(ls_))
```