# Can't remove gil on a C type extension iteration

Tags: python, cython

I don't understand why I'm getting an error saying:

> discarding owned Python object not allowed without gil

My code is a C type extension so it really shouldn't be a Python object, yet I can't apply nogil in this case. I'm somewhat clueless as to why this is happening.

```
cdef class Fraction:

    cdef int _numerator
    cdef int _denominator
    cdef int numerator
    cdef int denominator

    def __cinit__(self, numerator=0, denominator=None, bint _normalize=True):

        self._numerator = numerator
        self._denominator = denominator


@cython.boundscheck(False) 
@cython.wraparound(False) 
cpdef gaussian_inverse_cy():

    cdef int a = 1, b = 2, i

    with nogil: 
        for i in prange(10000):
            Fraction(a,b)
```

Comment: It's indeed a Python object. cdef class let you create **a new built-in Python types** 
 http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#introduction , which cannot be created/manipulated without gil.

Comment: You might be able to put it in a small `with gil:` block. Obviously in this case that'd be the entire loop but in a real example it might only be a small fraction of the loop. I think you should still be able to access `cdef` attributes without the GIL (once it's created).

Comment: @MLhacker see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21135087/6037118

Answer (score 0):

`cdef class` defines new Python extension classes. Objects created from them are Python objects which require the GIL to be created or manipulated.

If what you want is a C structure that can be used without the GIL and conversely, not exposed in Python, can use a structure and map that to an extension class.

For example:

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from cython.parallel cimport prange

ctypedef struct _Fraction:
    int numerator
    int denominator

cdef _Fraction * create_fraction(int numerator, int denominator) nogil:
    # Example, needs error checking, freeing, etc
    _fraction = <_Fraction *>malloc(sizeof(_Fraction))
    _fraction.numerator = numerator
    _fraction.denominator = denominator
    return _fraction

cpdef gaussian_inverse_cy():
    cdef int a = 1, b = 2, i
    with nogil:
        for i in prange(10000):
            my_fract = create_fraction(a,b)
            # <do something with my_fract>
```

The above compiles and runs fine, though obviously nothing is returned as a Python object.

To expose the fraction structure to Python you would create an extension class for it that uses a `_Fraction *` member, eg:

cdef class Fraction:
    cdef _Fraction *_fraction
    <..>

And assign `_fraction` to be a C pointer to the `_Fraction` structure after creating the object.