# Calling a cdef nogil function within nogil

Tags: python, c++, jupyter-notebook, cython, cpython

This question was partly covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691055/cant-remove-gil-on-a-c-type-extension-iteration), but I am not quite satisfied with the solution and am wondering:

1. is there a way around writing a structure and map it to an extension class
2. why does the error come up? The function is `cdef` *and* `nogil`, calling it in a GIL environment complies fine

The first point is quite important to me, since I will be calling a lot of functions from the `utils` library and writing everything in a manner described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691055/cant-remove-gil-on-a-c-type-extension-iteration) would be extremely time-consuming.

The code (iPython notebook):

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
mingw_setup_args={'script_args': ["--compiler=mingw32", "--cython-cplus"], 'include_dirs': np.get_include()}
import pyximport; pyximport.install(setup_args=mingw_setup_args, reload_support=True, language_level=3)

from utils import blas_multiply

D_TYPE = np.dtype(np.float64)

cdef double[:,:] A = np.random.randn(100, 10, dtype=D_TYPE)
cdef double[:] b = np.random.randn(10, dtype=D_TYPE)
cdef double[:] out = np.zeros((A.shape[0], ), dtype=D_TYPE)

# blas_multiply(A, b, out) # works fine

with nogil:
    blas_multiply(A, b, out)
```

The `utils.pyx` file

```
#!python
# distutils: language=c++
# cython: language_level=3

cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport scipy.linalg.cython_blas as blas

@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cpdef void blas_multiply(double[:,:] A, double[:] b, double[:] c) nogil:
    """
    calls dgemv from BLAS which computes y = alpha * trans(A) + beta * y
    A: m rows by k columns
    b: k rows by 1 columns
    c: k rows by 1 columns
    """
    cdef int m = A.shape[0]
    cdef int k = A.shape[1]
    cdef int n = 1
    cdef double alpha = 1.0
    cdef double beta = 0.0

    # for F contiguous arrays
    # blas.dgemv("N", &m, &k, &alpha, &A[0, 0], &m, &b[0], &n, &beta, &c[0], &n)

    # for C contiguous arrays
    blas.dgemv("T", &k, &m, &alpha, &A[0, 0], &k, &b[0], &n, &beta, &c[0], &n)
```

The traceback:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

# blas_multiply(A, b, out)
# print(out)

with nogil:
    blas_multiply(A, b, out)
                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\...\.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_6b53bffa20f1e5bcc572f847b4b26a3f.pyx:22:17: Discarding owned Python object not allowed without gil

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

# blas_multiply(A, b, out)
# print(out)

with nogil:
    blas_multiply(A, b, out)
                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\...\.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_6b53bffa20f1e5bcc572f847b4b26a3f.pyx:22:17: Calling gil-requiring function not allowed without gil

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

# blas_multiply(A, b, out)
# print(out)

with nogil:
    blas_multiply(A, b, out)
   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\...\.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_6b53bffa20f1e5bcc572f847b4b26a3f.pyx:22:4: Accessing Python global or builtin not allowed without gil

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

# blas_multiply(A, b, out)
# print(out)

with nogil:
    blas_multiply(A, b, out)
                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\...\.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_6b53bffa20f1e5bcc572f847b4b26a3f.pyx:22:17: Constructing Python tuple not allowed without gil

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

# blas_multiply(A, b, out)
# print(out)

with nogil:
    blas_multiply(A, b, out)
                 ^
------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\...\.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_6b53bffa20f1e5bcc572f847b4b26a3f.pyx:22:18: Converting to Python object not allowed without gil

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

# blas_multiply(A, b, out)
# print(out)

with nogil:
    blas_multiply(A, b, out)
                    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\...\.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_6b53bffa20f1e5bcc572f847b4b26a3f.pyx:22:21: Converting to Python object not allowed without gil

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

# blas_multiply(A, b, out)
# print(out)

with nogil:
    blas_multiply(A, b, out)
                       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\...\.ipython\cython\_cython_magic_6b53bffa20f1e5bcc572f847b4b26a3f.pyx:22:24: Converting to Python object not allowed without gil
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from utils import blas_multiply
```

This import `blas_multiply` as a *Python* function (i.e. the wrapper than `cpdef` generates). It therefore appears as a generic Python callable and all information about it being `nogil` is lost.

You want

```
from utils cimport blas_multiply
```

which gets the Cython definition of `blas_multiply` at *compile-time*. You will need to declare the signature of `blas_multiply` in a .pxd file for this to work correctly.

Comment: Ahh yes, thanks! Does that mean every function in `utils.pxy` would need its own `.pxd` file?

Comment: No. They'd all go in `utils.pxd`